# serving static files on GAE

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine

I'm trying to serve a test file with some javascript. My test site is loading, but the JS isn't loading with it (if I look in the devloper's console, I see there's a 404 error -- but the path is right). I first tried keeping everything in root.

edited: as loki pointed out this way is wrong

I also tried keeping everything in a file called static (except for the yaml file which was outside)

```
application: test
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /
  static_files: static/test.html
  upload: static/test.html
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing? I'm having trouble understanding why it won't see my javascript.

Update:

```
application: test
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /
  static_files: static/test.html
  upload: static/test.html

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

this fixes it. the second handle picks up the javascript (and everything else in static, i think)

Comment: As far as I know the upload `option` doesn't go with `static_dir` just with `static_files`

Comment: which handler do you expect to be invoked for an incoming URL of static/script.js ?

Comment: stuart: yea you're right. i'm confused about static_files and static_dir and how to use them. I updated my post above to show what I did to fix it

Comment: Could you move your solution to an answer so that this question shows up as answered?